# pdftk extract random pages from script variable

Tags: variables, pdf, split, extract

I have some pdf files about 2000 pages. They are randomly generated.
I need to extract some pages that contain some specific patterns, that changes its page number for every pdf.
With some steps using pdfToText and AWK, I can get the page numbers and I store some info into a csv file like that:

```
PatternA ; 1 3 5 7
PatternB ; 1 8 10 22
```

I have been trying to do a loop to get and process each line from this csv into the cat option from pdftk command, but it aways return error:

```
$IFS=$(printf '\n\t')
for line in `cat job.csv`
do 
pattern=`echo $line ¦ cut -d ';' -f 1` 
pages=`echo $line ¦ cut -d ';' - f 2` 
pdftk input.pdf cat $pages output $pattern
done
```

When echoing pattern and pages variables, everything are ok. But the pdftk command returns error if I try to get pages from $pages variable:

```
Error: Unexpected text in page range end, here: 
   1 3 5 7
   Exiting.
   Acceptable keywords, for example: "even" or "odd".
   To rotate pages, use: "north" "south" "east"
       "west" "left" "right" or "down"
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I guess.. I don't know if it is the best choice, but works:

Instead directly execute the pdftk command:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat $pages output $pattern
```

I stored entire command into a new variable and them, ran the eval command:

```
cmd="pdftk input.pdf cat $pages output $pattern"
eval $cmd
```

So, it worked like a charm...

If there are more elegant solution, I'll appreciate!